# What do you call the person sitting behind the driver on a bike?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I know *pillion* is a seat behind the rider of a horse or motorbike etc.

I would like to know the word for the person sitting on pillion.

Comment: The correct term might not be the most user friendly. Are you a casual rider or, for example, part of a cycling club?

Comment: @tylerharms no, i mean it for casual driver.

Comment: Note that, if riding a tandem bicycle (where the second person also pedals), that second person is called a *stoker* (at least in the US).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pillion is the right word for the person too. Source [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillion)

> A passenger in this seat is said to "ride pillion" or may themselves
>   be referred to as a "pillion".

Or you can say 'pillion rider' as in [these news articles](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22pillion%20rider%22).

Comment: You can certainly say that, but I don't know anyone who would understand it.

Comment: @Jim check additional link in answer about news articles using the term.

Comment: Ah, they are all from India or other places on the far side of the world from where I live.  Maybe that's a common term in some regions.  It's certainly not in the U.S.

Comment: It's OK in the UK.

Comment: For the UK, 'pillion passenger' is also common.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in casual conversation, you can just call them the **person in back**, but if you need to be [technical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_bicycle), they can be called the

**stoker**, **navigator**, **[tailgunner](http://sheldonbrown.com/tandem.html)** or **rear admiral**.

Those words are fantastic, IMHO, but they are esoteric to most casual bike riders. Best to stick with "front/rear rider" or "person in front/back".

Answer (score 1):

If the motorcycle passenger is a girl, you might consider [***back warmer***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_motorcycling_terms)

> back warmer: a girl on the back of your motorcycle
>
> [Total Motorcycle](http://www.totalmotorcycle.com/dictionary/B.htm)

Comment: That would be one of the more proper terms......http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Riding+Bitch

Answer (score 1):

I call that person the passenger. "bicycle passenger" gets 28 million hits on Google, "bicycle pillion" gets 370 thousand.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, I'd refer to that person as "[riding shotgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riding_shotgun)", although that usually is in reference to riding beside the driver in a car.  It's origins appear to come from riding stagecoaches.

It's a more recent phrase than riding pillion, [per ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riding%20shotgun%2Criding%20pillion&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Criding%20shotgun%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Criding%20pillion%3B%2Cc0).  Ngram does support that usage "riding pillion" is more common in British English than American English.

Much, much less common is the term "Wookie", originating from the film "Fanboys".  The passenger assumes the role of Chewbacca, the Wookie, implying the driver is Han Solo, and the vehicle in question is the Millenium Falcon.

Answer (score -3):

"Tandem" is what I would use, as in "riding tandem".

Comment: In the UK at least, *tandem* is [something completely different](http://www.tandems.co.uk/).

Comment: Oh, well, I did not know that.