# What do you call the person who gives a ride?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

1. Is there a word to call someone who gives a ride?
2. What do you call the person who gets a ride?

Comment: "Driver" and "passenger" are all-purpose terms that might suit your needs.

Comment: Whistling for a cab is traditional.

Comment: The person+car is "a lift".  "Do you need a ride home, Frank?"  "No thanks, I have a lift."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just call the person providing the ride a **ride**

Google definition:

> NORTH AMERICAN
>
> a person giving someone a lift in their vehicle.

"John is my ride to the airport."

The person who gets the ride is a **passenger**.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a word to call someone who gives a ride? 
Answer - He/she is called a rider when riding bike/bicycle, driver in case of other vehicles, equestrian while riding a horse.

How do you call the person who get a ride?
Answer - "Pillion" or "ride pillion" in case of two-wheeler and horse. Passenger or fellow-passenger when driving a car.

Reference - [What do you call the person sitting behind the driver on a bike?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141944/what-do-you-call-the-person-sitting-behind-the-driver-on-a-bike)

Comment: None of the words you suggest imply that a ride is being provided to somebody else, they're just the standard words for the person in control of the vehicle or animal, with or without any additional passengers.